# WPF DataBinding ListBox in MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am databind Listbox in MVVM pattern,I am using Entity Framework for getting data,this is how I am doing

XAML:

```
<ListBox Margin="0,26,860,-146" x:Name="lstuser" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxDS}"/>
```

C# code:

```
private ObservableCollection<Users> _lstusers;
public ObservableCollection<Users> ListBoxDS
{
    get
    {
        if (_lstusers == null)
        {
            _lstusers = new ObservableCollection<Users>();
        }
        return _lstusers;
    }
    set
    {
        _lstusers = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("ListBoxDS");
    }
}


public class Users
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

DataContext:

```
public static IList<Users> GetAllUsers
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationContext())               
        {
            return context.UsersInfo.ToList();
        }
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

and in my ViewModel

```
var allusersList=GetAllUsers();
     var users = allusersList.Where(a => a.FirstName =="some value").ToList();
                        foreach (var item in users)
                        {
                            _lstusers.Add(new Users { UserID = item.Id, UserName = item.Username,FirstName=item.firstname });
                        }
```

When I am ruuning my project,its not showing any item in Listbox, I am following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119900/wpf-listbox-bind-itemssource-with-mvvm-light)
I have debugged it, data is appearing in ListDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code i cant see that you add the item to your list. it should be

```
var users = allusersList.Where(a => a.FirstName =="some value").ToList();
foreach (var item in users)
{
      ListBoxDS.Add(new Users { UserID = item.Id, UserName = item.Username,FirstName=item.firstname });
 }
```

EDIT: then your code should work if you set the right DataContext. you can check this with Snoop at runtime.

Comment: I am adding in _lstusers, Please see my updated question

Comment: pls post the code where you set the DataContext. this should be the problem